# в файле strings.xml сделать отступ от начала строки

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Как сделать отступ от начала строки?
В Design все выглядит как надо, но при запуске на устройстве текст съезжает на начало строки.

Только начал учить Android Studio и Kotlin

Comment: Никак, там целиком строка. Отступ пробелами вы в коде можете установить. Или сдвинуть разметку

Answer (score 1):

**Если** вам нужна красная строка в тексте, то можете добавить в текст табуляцию `\t` и это будет эквивалентно 4 пробелам

**Если** нужно сместить весь текст, то в файле разметки (в папке layout) с расширением .xml следует добавить к TextView параметр `android:layout_marginStart="10dp"`. Поиграйтесь: 10dp измените на своё значение чтобы вам понравилось при просмотре в Design. Если параметр будет подчёркнут красным, то используйте `android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"` - в некторых случаях помогает, но это устаревший параметр.

Answer (score 0):

Я делал так:

*В strings*

```
<string name="somestring">##indent##Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</string>
```

*В фрагменте*

```
...
const val INDENT_PLACEHOLDER = "##indent##"
const val INDENT_VALUE = "      "
...
view.text = getString(R.strings.somestring).replace(INDENT_PLACEHOLDER, INDENT_VALUE)
```